# what does "layout-compatible with C" mean?

Tags: c++, c, stl, vector

It is said that stl vector is "layout-compatible with C".
Where can I find the definition of "layout-compatible with C"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This means that, as long as the vector is not empty, `&vector.front()` will give you a pointer to a contiguous array of objects, which could be passed to a C API that expects such an array.

Answer (score 4):

It means that the contents of the vector will be laid out in memory the same way they would be in a C array of the same type. That means that if you have a C function that expects to receive a pointer to an array of some type, you can use a vector and pass the function a pointer to the first element of the vector.